# Multiple Static Directories in Python Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I have a directory structure setup like:

```
root/
  js/
  css/
  libs/
  index.html
```

From Tornado, I want to serve js, css, and libs as static directories, but I can only find out how to serve one of them. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No its not possible.

You could ofcourse create a new folder -- parent, and place js, css and libs inside of that folder, and then speciy that parent folder as the 'static_path'

nb. "In production, you probably want to serve static files from a more optimized static file server like [nginx](http://nginx.org/)"

Answer (score 4):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10165739/1813988

You can set the static path for different assets by setting handlers like this (and remove the `static_path` setting in Application):

> ```
> handlers = [
>             (r'/favicon.ico', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path':  favicon_path}),
>             (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': static_path}),
>             (r'/', WebHandler)
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

As Schildmeijer quoted from the Tornado website, I recommend using Nginx to serve static files.  Having this setup early on is very convenient and easy.  This also allows you some other potential benefits in the future:

- Using Nginx for load balancing
- Using Nginx to handle SSL