# How to serve static files from a different directory than the static path?

Tags: python, static, tornado, favicon

I am trying this:

```
favicon_path = '/path/to/favicon.ico'

settings = {'debug': True, 
            'static_path': os.path.join(PATH, 'static')}

handlers = [(r'/', WebHandler),
            (r'/favicon.ico', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': favicon_path})]

application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)
application.listen(port)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

But it keeps serving the `favicon.ico` that I have in my static_path (I have two different `favicon.ico`'s in two separate paths, as indicated above, but I want to be able to override the one in the `static_path`).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Delete [`static_path`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L1907) from the app settings.

Then set your handler like:

```
handlers = [
            (r'/(favicon\.ico)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': favicon_path_dir}),
            (r'/static/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': static_path_dir}),
            (r'/', WebHandler)
]
```

Comment: Okay, I got this to work by changing it to r'/(favicon\.ico)'. Why did that work? (I copied it from a similar example in the docs.)

Comment: seems like setting static_path in the app settings has a special case for favicon and robots.txt. from the docs: `we will serve /favicon.ico and /robots.txt from the same [static_path] directory`

Comment: @shino It worked because r'/favicon.ico' is a regular expression and you correctly escaped the '.'

Comment: Well it would have still matched a literal '.'. The reason that worked is that matched regex groups get passed as arguments to methods of a `RequestHandler`. The premade `StaticFileHandler` class expects the path of the file it is looking for relative to either the "static_path" setting or the "path" member on the handlers class. The {'path': static_path} get's passed to the handlers `initialize` method which then sets it on the instance.

Comment: @shino you need to extract one group with the filename to serve, I guess. Brackets in regular expression do just that. Try to remove it, and it will tell you `TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'`, but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap favicon.ico with parenthesis and escape the period in the regular expression. Your code will become

```
favicon_path = '/path/to/favicon.ico' # Actually the directory containing the favicon.ico file

settings = {
    'debug': True, 
    'static_path': os.path.join(PATH, 'static')}

handlers = [
    (r'/', WebHandler),
    (r'/(favicon\.ico)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': favicon_path})]

application = tornado.web.Application(handlers, **settings)
application.listen(port)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

### There are two ways to do it.

#### 1. use *static_url_prefix* in settings.

e.g.

```
settings = dict(
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'),
    static_url_prefix="/adtrpt/static/",
)
```

#### 2. use custom handler

Append custom handler to handlers

```
handlers.append((r"/adtrpt/static/(.*)", MyStaticFileHandler, {"path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')}))
```

Then implemente your custom methods.

```
class StaticHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        path = self.request.path
        print(path)
        self.redirect(BASE_URI + path)
```