# How to use static file in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

How do you use static path in Tornado?

I've tried the following configuration:

```
settings = {
    'static_path' : 'static'
}
```

But it's not working.

For example, I have this line in my HTML:

```
<link href="/static/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I open this URL: `http://localhost/static/bootstrap.css`

I'm see an error: `404 Not Found`

Can anyone explain how to configure static paths in Tornado?

Comment: You really shouldn't serve static content with tornado, that's not it's purpose (see nginx for example). If you really want to (simpler dev env, maybe) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165665/using-tornado-how-do-i-serve-static-files-and-serve-a-favicon-ico-from-a-differ has a great example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to change your settings dict to the following, assuming you're running the file from the same location as the static folder:

```
settings = dict(
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
    )
```

Then in your html template you need to use [`static_url`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html?highlight=static_url#tornado.web.RequestHandler.static_url):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static_url("bootstrap.css") }}" />
```

Comment: When I was learning how to use Tornado the [`examples on github helped alot!`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/master/demos)