# Several static directories for tornado

Tags: python, tornado, assets

We are building uServices based on tornado. There are some routes which are common for all uServices, for the time being `health` and `docs`. The docs route is built using `Swagger`. That means, the swagger route, and associated assets, are part of our common library (but not the documentation itself, which is uService related), which is simply a requirement to our uServices.

Since swagger needs static assets, and each uService needs its own static assets too, I have a problem: my static assets are coming from two completely different places. I have found a (very inconvenient) hack to solve this:

1. track static assets in the common repo
2. track static assets in the uService repo
3. when deploying, copy those static assets, from both sources, to a deployment static folder (and hope that there are no clashes)
4. specify the deployment static folder as the `static_path`

Step 3 is quite complex, because it involves pip-installing the common library, finding the assets there (already a hack), and copying them around:

- install the common library with pip
- look for the location of the installed library (`site-packages`)
- copy the static assets to the deployment static folder

It would be much easier if, as happens with the [`template_path`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_template_path), it would be possible to have a per-application static folder:

```
> Return None to load templates relative to the calling file.
```

I have been searching the web, and it seems [this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3935046/647991), but I wanted to double check.

An alternative would be to simplify asset extracting from a packaged python module, but not sure what is the preferred method to do this, without having  to recur to hacks searching in the `virtualenv` for the `site-packages`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this with the `static_path` setting, but as long as you don't require the `static_url()` function, you can create multiple `StaticFileHandler` entries in your URLSpec list:

```
Application([
    ('/static1/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path='static1')),
    ('/static2/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path='static1')),
])
```

As a substitute for `static_url`, you can call `StaticFileHandler.make_static_url` and pass it the arguments that would have been global if you were using `static_path`.